# Articulation switches in NI Battery 3

Tags: untagged

Is there any way to create articulation keyswitches in NI Battery 3 in the same way it is done in Kontakt?

For example, I want to have a single snare drum cell and make it play with or without flams depending on a MIDI event, which may be a 0-octave note which serves like a switch, or an automation event.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if Battery supports using MIDI notes as switches the way Kontakt does, but you can link a MIDI CC macro to most of Battery's controls. Check the manual for details on how to do it.